# regexp match in specific word in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I'm searching though IIS log files looking for lines where the 6th word contains h3.asp

Tried to make a regular expression, but it's failing:

```
string text = @"2010-08-28 00:12:15 W3SVC591993719 192.168.10.13 GET /forum/h3.asp g=forum 80 - 10.10.10.10 Opera/9.80+(S60;+SymbOS;+Opera+Mobi/499;+U;+no)+Presto/2.4.18+Version/10.00 http://www.somesite.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=28078& www.somesite.com 200 0 0 62";

string pattern = @"(\w* ){5}\w*h3\.asp";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern));
```

In the above sample I'm expecting a match, but clearly something is wrong.

Comment: always google for things like this http://www.regextester.com/ they can be so helpful

Comment: not sure about IIS but in pcre \w is word chars 'A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character. i.e. ':' will break match. You're better off broadening your match since space is actually all you care about.

Comment: @Chimmoo I did google first. I found some references to something similar. That's how I managed to create my first expression. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
 string pattern = @"(\S+\s){5}\S*?h3\.asp";
```

\S will match all non-whitespace, so this regex will match 5 groups consisting of non-whitespace followed by a single whitespace, followed by anything that contains "h3.asp"

Answer (score 1):

\w only includes a-z

you might be better off doing something along the lines of:

```
@"(.+?\s+){5}.+?h3\.asp";
```

I didn't get to test it, but hopefully you'll see the difference